# Duplicate files with same content

Tags: filesystems

I was trying to implement a system where a user can save custom configurations. 
My query to the teacher was "Why should I allow the user to have multiple custom configurations that are 100% same with different names?" To this query, my teacher responded with an example of the file system where I can save multiple duplicate files.

I am not very convinced by this response although it is true.

I want to know why do we allow the user to save duplicate files or in my case duplicate configurations? I believe it is just redundancy and wastage of available space which can be avoided.

Comment: Personally, I like to make "Ghetto Backups" where I take my whole workspace, date the name, and zip it up. It might be identical to the zip file I made a day before but I have a backup of it on two different drives, in-case one drive breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two configurations may be the same today, but next week one of them will be changed to do something different. Until then, it is a good idea to get used to loading ConfigA for JobA, and ConfigB for JobB. They are the same now, but next week ConfigB will change.